# /etc/profile.d and "ssh -t"

Tags: linux, ssh, sles

I wanted to run a script on a remote machine. The simple solution is this:

```
ssh remote1 some-script
```

This works until the remote script doesn't want to connect to another remote machine (`remote2`) which requires interactive authentication, like tis one (`remote2` is only reachable through `remote1` in this case):

```
ssh remote1 "ssh remote2 some-script"
```

The solution for the problem is to use the `-t` option for ssh.

```
ssh -t remote1 "ssh remote2 some-script"
```

This works, but I get probems in case I use this (where `some-script` may execute further ssh commands):

```
ssh -t remote1 some-script
```

I found that some environment variables are not set which are set when I don't use the `-t` option. These envrionment variables are set in scripts from `/etc/profile.d`. I guess that these scripts are not run for some reason if using the `-t` option, but are run if I don't use it.

What's the reason of this? Is there any way to work around it? I am using SUSE linux (version 10).

**Edit:** I did some additional research. I put some output lines to the following places:

- in one file in `/etc/profile.d`
- in `~/.bash_profile` (file didn't exist before)
- in `~/.bashrc` (file didn't exist before)

Then I checked several scenarios what output I get and in what order (the environment variable I checked is `$PATH`):

- `ssh remote1`: `profile.d`, `.bashrc`, `.bash_profile`. `$PATH` OK.
- `ssh -t remote1`: `profile.d`, `.bashrc`, `.bash_profile`. `$PATH` OK.
- `ssh remote1 echo '$PATH'`: only `.bashrc`. `$PATH` OK.
- `ssh -t remote1 echo '$PATH'`: no script output. `$PATH` NOK.

Now I really don't understand what's going on. If I run an interactive shell, everything seems to be working fine (though I find it strange that `~/.bashrc` is included before `~/.bash_profile`). If I start a non-interactive shell without `-t`, profile scripts don't seem to run but environment variables are set. If I start a non-interactive shell with `-t`, then profile scrtipts are not run and environment variables are not set. Does anyone have an explanation on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't find the reason of the problem. Maybe it's specific for the platform (SLES 10 or the variation I use). I found a workaround instead:

```
ssh -t remote1 "/bin/bash --login -c some-script"
```

This forces a login shell which runs profile scripts.

Answer (score 0):

All questions are answered in the "INVOCATION" section of the bash man page:

> When bash is invoked as an interactive login shell, or as a
>          non-interactive shell with the --login option, it first reads and
>          executes commands  from  the file  /etc/profile,  if  that file exists.
>          After reading that file, it looks for ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login,
>          and ~/.profile, in that order, and reads and executes commands from the
>          first one that exists and is readable.  The --noprofile option may be
>          used when the shell is started to inhibit this behavior.
>
> When a login shell exits, bash reads and executes commands from the file
>          ~/.bash_logout, if it exists.
>
> When  an interactive shell that is not a login shell is started, bash
>          reads and executes commands from ~/.bashrc, if that file exists.  This
>          may be inhibited by using the --norc option.  The --rcfile file option
>          will force bash to read and execute commands from file instead of
>          ~/.bashrc.

As you can see, interactive shells only source `.bashrc`, and often `.bash_profile` would be sourced from there, which explains the order that you are seeing.

Very often, these files also have a condition to only parse certain sections for interactive shells only (`[[ $- == *i* ]]`), which would explain why some parts might appear to be missing for non-interactive shells.

Comment: This still does not explain the difference between calling ssh with and without `-t`. I also checked the appropriate `profile.d` file and `/etc/profile`. In `profile.d` there are no special checks for setting `$PATH`. In `/etc/profile` the only check is that `$PROFILEREAD` is empty, wich is set at the end of that script. I checked, this variable is set when I run ssh without `-t`, but not if I run it with `-t`.

Comment: The only difference between `ssh server command` and `ssh -t server command` is the presence of a tty. Have you checked if any of the files in `/etc/profile.d` are doing such checks? grep for `tty` or `TERM` and see what that brings about.

Comment: As I said, the files in `/etc/profile.d` has no such conditions. I also checked `/etc/profile`, again not containing such conditions. It is possible that it is a platform specific problem on this system, but I can't find the cause.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between

```
ssh remote1 echo '$PATH'
```

and

```
ssh -t remote1 echo '$PATH'
```

is also explained in the bash manpage:

> Bash attempts to determine when it is being run with its standard input connected to a network connection, as when executed by the remote shell daemon, usually `rshd`, or the secure shell daemon `sshd`. If bash determines it is being run in this fashion, it reads and executes commands from `~/.bashrc` [I assume that should read `/etc/bash.bashrc`] and `~/.bashrc`, if these files exist and are readable.

In the first example, `bash`'s stdin is connected to a network connection, so it runs `~/.bashrc`. In the second, its stdin comes from a pseudo-terminal, so it doesn't.